# Pipedrive: PUT to update filter from vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba, pipedrive-api

I'm trying to update a filter in Pipedrive CRM;
[Pipedrive API Ref](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/?_ga=2.42896229.1164545172.1531365598-1698388143.1531365598#!/Filters/put_filters_id)

Using;

```
strURL = strURL & “/filters/{25}?api_token=” & strToken
'https://xx.pipedrive.com/v1/filters/{25}?api_token=xx

'Set filter 
With CreateObject(“MSXML2.XMLHTTP”) 
.Open “PUT”, strURL, False 
.setRequestHeader “Content-Type”, “application/json” 
.Send (strSql) 
txt = .responseText 
End With'
```

Which returns;

```
{“status”:false,“error”:“Unknown method .”}
```

Very new to Pipedrive API and never PUT before!

The filter JSON is;

`strSql = "{" & Chr(34) & "glue" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "and" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "conditions" & Chr(34) & ":[{" & Chr(34) & "glue" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) _
        & "and" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "conditions" & Chr(34) & ": [{" & Chr(34) & "object" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "organization" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) _
        & "field_id" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "3997" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "operator" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "<" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "value" & Chr(34) _
        & ":" & Chr(34) & VarCreated & Chr(34) & "},{" & Chr(34) & "object" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "organization" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "field_id" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) _
        & "3998" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "operator" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & ">" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "value" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & VarUpdated & Chr(34) _
        & "}]},{" & Chr(34) & "glue" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "or" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "conditions" & Chr(34) & ":[]}]}"`

Comment: And what is the strSQL?

Comment: Filter conditions as a JSON object.

`{"glue":"and","conditions":[{"glue":"and","conditions": [{"object":"organization","field_id":"3997","operator":"<","value":"2018-07-12 12:00:00"},{"object":"organization","field_id":"3998","operator":">","value":"2018-07-12 12:00:00"}]},{"glue":"or","conditions":[]}]}`

Comment: [https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/?_ga=2.42896229.1164545172.1531365598-1698388143.1531365598#!/Filters/put_filters_id](https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/?_ga=2.42896229.1164545172.1531365598-1698388143.1531365598#!/Filters/put_filters_id)

Answer (score 0):

> The answer Dear Reader is; You have to send the whole filter JSON - Not just the conditions.
>   Nowhere I can see is this documented!

This is the syntax to Create/Update a Filter from [Stackoverflow.com/questions/43493333](http://Stackoverflow.com/questions/43493333)

> { “name”:“OrgUpdated”, “type”:“org”, “visible_to”:1, “conditions”:{ “glue”: “and”, “conditions”:[ { “glue”: “and”, “conditions”: [ { “object”: “organization”, “field_id”: “3997”, “operator”: “<”, “value”: “18/08/2018”, “extra_value”: null },{ “object”: “organization”, “field_id”: “3998”, “operator”: “>”, “value”: “18/08/2018”, “extra_value”: null } ] }, { “glue”: “or”,“conditions”: [] } ] } }

In vba;

```
'added
‘strJSON = "{ ‘name’:‘OrgCreated’, ‘type’:‘org’, ‘visible_to’:1, ‘conditions’:{ ‘glue’: ‘and’, ‘conditions’:[ { ‘glue’: ‘and’, ‘conditions’: [ { " _
’ & “‘object’: ‘organization’, ‘field_id’: ‘3997’, ‘operator’: ‘>’, ‘value’: '” & dteCreated & "’, ‘extra_value’: null } ] }, { ‘glue’: ‘or’," _
’ & “‘conditions’: [] } ] } }”

‘Updated
strJSON = "{ ‘name’:‘OrgUpdated’, ‘type’:‘org’, ‘visible_to’:1, ‘conditions’:{ ‘glue’: ‘and’, ‘conditions’:[ { ‘glue’: ‘and’, ‘conditions’: [ " _
& “{ ‘object’: ‘organization’, ‘field_id’: ‘3997’, ‘operator’: ‘<’, ‘value’: '” & dteCreated & "’, ‘extra_value’: null }," _
& “{ ‘object’: ‘organization’, ‘field_id’: ‘3998’, ‘operator’: ‘>’, ‘value’: '” & dteUpdated & “’, ‘extra_value’: null } ] }, { ‘glue’: ‘or’,” _
& “‘conditions’: [] } ] } }”

strJSON = Replace(strJSON, "'", """")

Debug.Print strJSON
```

Note well that Pipedrive uses relative time, so the date variable is from the available list; today, yesterday, last_week etc.

Here is a set of functions to do Filters with;

```
Public Function CreateFilter(FilterJSON As String) As String
’ Returns Filter ID if created or error if not
Dim strURL As String, strToken As String, txt As String
Dim strSql As String, s As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

strURL = DLookup("[URL]", "tblCRMDetails")
strToken = DLookup("[Token]", "tblCRMDetails")

strURL = strURL & "/filters?api_token=" & strToken
’ Debug.Print strURL

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "POST", URL, False
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send (FilterJSON)
    txt = .ResponseText
End With
 Debug.Print txt

CreateFilter = txt

i = InStr(txt, "id")
If i > 0 Then
    s = "0"
    j = 0
    Do Until Not IsNumeric(s)
        j = j + 1
        s = Mid(txt, i + 3 + j, 1)
    Loop
    s = Mid(txt, i + 4, j - 1)
    CreateFilter = s
End If
End Function

Public Function DeleteFilter(ID As Long) As Boolean
’ Returns True if Filter Deleted
Dim strURL As String, strToken As String, txt As String
Dim strSql As String, s As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

strURL = DLookup("[URL]", "tblCRMDetails")
strToken = DLookup("[Token]", "tblCRMDetails")

strURL = strURL & "/filters/" & ID & "?api_token=" & strToken

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1
    .Open "DELETE", URL, False
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send
    txt = .ResponseText
End With
’ Debug.Print txt

    'check success
If InStr(txt, "success"":true") > 0 Then
    DeleteFilter = True
End If
End Function

Public Function UpdateFilter(ID As Long, FilterJSON As String) As String
’ Returns Filter ID if created or error if not
’ txt = UpdateFilter(40, strSql)
Dim strURL As String, strToken As String, txt As String
Dim strSql As String, s As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

strURL = DLookup("[URL]", "tblCRMDetails")
strToken = DLookup("[Token]", "tblCRMDetails")

strURL = strURL & "/filters/" & ID & "?api_token=" & strToken

With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "PUT", strURL, False
    .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send (FilterJSON)
    txt = .ResponseText
End With
Debug.Print txt

UpdateFilter = txt

i = InStr(txt, "id")
If i > 0 Then
    s = "0"
    j = 0
    Do Until Not IsNumeric(s)
        j = j + 1
        s = Mid(txt, i + 3 + j, 1)
    Loop
    s = Mid(txt, i + 4, j - 1)
    UpdateFilter = s
End If
End Function
```